# Inputting an array into Math.Max in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In a Google sheet, I have a custom form based off of some posts/blogs that I have found online to learn more about Google App Scripts. The form works correctly but I am having trouble with the column that should be creating an ID for the row.

From my reading, it seems that my problem is that math.max() takes a list not an array. Furthermore, none of the methods that I found for regular Javascript seem to be working in Google Apps Scripts. Such as, math.max.apply(null,array).

Do I have to iterate the array or is there something to make max() take an array?

Here is the code that I have been playing with.

```
function itemAdd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var range = sh.getRange(3,1,lRow,1);
  var maxNum = Math.max(range)
  sheet.appendRow([maxNum,form.category, form.item, form.manupub, 
form.details, form.quantity]);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Math.max.apply()` at GAS. And data retrieved by getValues() is a 2 dimensional array. So in order to use the data for `Math.max.apply()`, the array has to be flattened. By reflecting this, the sample script can be modified as follows.

#### Script :

```
function itemAdd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var range = sh.getRange(3,1,lRow,1);
  var ar = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], range.getValues());
  var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, ar);
  sheet.appendRow([maxNum,form.category, form.item, form.manupub, form.details, form.quantity]);
  return true;
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

An neat alternative with [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)and the spread operator [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var vals = range.getValues().flat();
var max = Math.max(...vals)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should help.  You need to extract the values from the range.  This will return a 2 dimensional array.

```
var vals = range.getValues();
//assuming your values are non negative, set the initial max to 0
var max = 0;
for(var i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
  max = Math.max(max, vals[i][0]);
}
//max will now have the largest value
```