# Check highest digit and copy text from grid cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to scripting, but need to do the following in Google sheet script for my RPG gaming system...

1. Check a cell for the highest one-digit number. i.e. 1  6  3  2  4 = 6 highest number.
2. Check the same in another cell.
3. Depending on the combo of these digits, i.e. 6-2, 3-4, 1-6 etc, text from a specific cell in a grid table on another sheet should be copied.
4. The grid has 1 to 6 vertically, and 1 to 6 horizontally, different texts in each combo cell.
5. The copied text shall be entered into a specific cell (i.e. E10) in the first sheet.

Can someone help me?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Show your attempt. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000 words.

Comment: ok.. give me a few hours and I will share a copy of my sheet for you to check, with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you would like to check the highest value in two cell, and would like to use that to get an exact location in a table of values, and get that value printed on another cell.

The problem can be solved in 3 phases.
1) Finding the highest value in the cell.
2) Retrieving the value in the table.
3) Setting the destination cell with the retrieved value.

1) Depending on if you are finding the highest value in a cell refers to:

A) 1534 in one cell and taking 5
OR
B) 1 in A1, 5 in A2, 3 in A3 and 4 in A4. and retrieving 5 from A2 cell.

A: Your solution would use a combination of **.split()** & **Array.prototype.concat.apply()** & **Math.max.apply()**. Reference: [Inputting an array into Math.Max in Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202902/inputting-an-array-into-math-max-in-google-apps-scripts)
B: Your solution would use a combination of **getRange(row,column,row,column)** & **Array.prototype.concat.apply()** & **Math.max.apply()**

You would get an output of two max number, which we would call A and B

2) To retrieve the value, you would require the **getRange(A,B)** & **getValue()** and depending on where the table is you might need to modify A and B to get the correct location in the table.

3) To set the value in cell E1, you would require the **setValue()** function.

You might want to try resolving the issue by yourself using the handles above. They might not be the most efficient, but should work. Alternatively i have a sample script below for you. There is a flaw, whereby if the value input is larger than your table, it would not flag out an error. so either you limit the users input or you would create a way to flag out the error:)

```
function SetRetrievedValue() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //var cellcontent1 = sheet.getRange(2,1,6,1).getValues(); use this if its a range of cells you are searching
  var cell1 = sheet.getRange(1,1).getDisplayValue(); //gets value as string
  var cellcontent1 = cell1.split(""); // splits up the string individually
  var newcellcontent1 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], cellcontent1); // flatten the array
  var maxNum1 = Math.max.apply(null, newcellcontent1); //gets the max value in the array

  // repeat of cell 1
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange(1,2).getDisplayValue(); 
  var cellcontent2 = cell2.split("");
  var newcellcontent2 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], cellcontent2);
  var maxNum2 = Math.max.apply(null, newcellcontent2);


  var tablecell = ss.getSheetByName("Table sheet").getRange(maxNum1,maxNum2).getValue(); //retrieve the value based on the corresponding max value
  sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue(tablecell); // sets the cell C1 as the value retrieved from the table
}
```

Comment: Thaaanksss!!!! This script will do it I Think. Just one more slight request.. in the RPG game certain combos of dice values, like 666 and 111 has its own functions. Such will have their own columns/rows in the table.

The cells to read the highest value from have a dice roll script that creates a series of numbers between 1 and 6 like this.. "1   2   6   3", with spaces inbetween. To simulate dice rolls.

Would it be possible for you to update the script to include reading of combos of dice result as well, so that such combo directs to a specific column/row?

Comment: Hi Snookie, i would suggest opening a new request for this as it is a different matter from your post. I would answer you on that post. Kindly accept the answer if it works for you, thank you.

Comment: I tried to do that but I have reached the limit of my questions it seems. I cannot post again a new question until a few days from now. I tried out your script. It works perfectly!!! Now I only need to add the combo dice thing.

Comment: please accept the answer so that this post can be shown as answered, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261990/rpg-gaming-dice-roll-skill-checker-script-question

Comment: I put the question as a new post. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: How do I accept the answer? I find no buttons for this?

Comment: Think I found it!