# RPG gaming dice roll skill checker script question

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For my RPG gaming skill check script... In the below script (created by Edmund chan kei yun, a member at StackOverflow) cells are checked for the highest numbers (after simulated several d6 dice rolls by another script), and then text is copied from a table (to define resulting actions).

I would also need dice result combos like 666 and 111 to have their own table results. Such will have their own columns/rows in the table. Could someone help me to update the script to include the reading of combos of dice result as well, so that such combo directs to a specific column/row?

Here is a link to an editable version of the sheet with script...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zYhUnlHCW7kfo0rf1pZY2GNI4qt5PsbGYOljFe2dwJE/edit?usp=sharing

```
function SetRetrievedValue() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //var cellcontent1 = sheet.getRange(2,1,6,1).getValues(); use this if its a range of cells you are searching
  var cell1 = sheet.getRange(1,1).getDisplayValue(); //gets value as string
  var cellcontent1 = cell1.split(""); // splits up the string individually
  var newcellcontent1 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], cellcontent1); // flatten the array
  var maxNum1 = Math.max.apply(null, newcellcontent1); //gets the max value in the array

  // repeat of cell 1
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange(1,2).getDisplayValue(); 
  var cellcontent2 = cell2.split("");
  var newcellcontent2 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], cellcontent2);
  var maxNum2 = Math.max.apply(null, newcellcontent2);


  var tablecell = ss.getSheetByName("Table sheet").getRange(maxNum1,maxNum2).getValue(); //retrieve the value based on the corresponding max value
  sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue(tablecell); // sets the cell C1 as the value retrieved from the table
}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand the working principle of your script without seeing a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: If the script is created by a member, it's better to credit him in the post. Also, what have you done or tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: I have now edited the post question to include script author name and sample sheet link. Would be very grateful for help. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your situation better. Right now your script retrieves values from cells `A1` and `A2`, but those cells are empty in your spreadsheet.  Are those cells expected to contain values like `111` and `666`? And if so - what is supposed to happen? You want to look up the combination in sheet `Flight_Table`? And after this?

Comment: The script reads from "Fight_table", and put text in a cell on the first tab depending on the combo of the one highest values the dice roll cells on the first table.

Comment: Edmund chan kei yun... do you want to help adjust the script? Very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be better if you adjust the script by yourself, but what i can help you with is the checking for specific combos. what you would want is to check for combo cases prior to checking for highest value, since combos take precedence.

Since the only combos are 666 and 111, we can use an if statement to change the row/column that is checked to 7. Therefore this is the only addition you would need to your script.

```
  if (newcellcontent1[0]=== '6' && newcellcontent1[0]===newcellcontent1[1] && newcellcontent1[1]===newcellcontent1[2]) { //if attacker rolls a 666
    maxNum1 = 7;
  }
  if (newcellcontent2[0]=== '1' && newcellcontent2[0]===newcellcontent2[1] && newcellcontent2[1]===newcellcontent2[2]) { //if defender rolls a 111
    maxNum2 = 7;
  }
  
  var tablecell = ss.getSheetByName("Table sheet").getRange(maxNum1,maxNum2).getValue(); //retrieve the value based on the corresponding max value
  sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue(tablecell); // sets the cell C1 as the value retrieved from the table
```

Please try to make any minor changes to the script by yourself. This is the google sheet that i used https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSpdsqQ2-c20EANnYoiKWQHNTu05C-7NGr0Y7K9on8A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried it but can't get it to work. What do I do wrong? It needs to change the value of maxNum1 and maxNum2 in the if sentance as I have put them?...

Comment: var newcellcontent1 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], cellcontent1); // flatten the array 
  var maxNum1 = Math.max.apply(null, newcellcontent1); //gets the max value in the array
  if (newcellcontent1[0]=== '6' && newcellcontent1[0]===newcellcontent1[1] && newcellcontent1[1]===newcellcontent1[2]) { //if attacker rolls a 666
    maxNum1 = 7;
  }

Comment: you would need to input this script after the line var maxNum2 = Math.max.apply(null, newcellcontent2); no other changes would be required

Comment: I did as you told and put all the new script above just under the "maxNum2 = Math.max.apply(null, newcellcontent2);" line, aka at the end of the script just before the "var tablecell..." line (which you included in the script addon above).But it doesn't pick up 111 or 666. What do I do wrong?

Comment: currently it tracks 666 for cell 1 and 111 for cell 2, if you want cell 1 to track 111, change newcellcontent1[0]=== '6' to newcellcontent1[0]=== '1'. And if you want it to track any combo, remove this line.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. It won't read row 7 for newcellcontent1 if 666, nor column 7 for newcellcontent2 if 111. Please give more detailed advise. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have now put in the code in the sample sheet linked to above, also linked here. I still can't get it to work...https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zYhUnlHCW7kfo0rf1pZY2GNI4qt5PsbGYOljFe2dwJE/edit#gid=1363591367