# How to repeat function for all filled in cells (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This Function is currently only saving the max price on C4 and puts out to D4.
How can i make this function go through all filled-in cells from C4:C2000 and put out the max price to D4:D2000?

```
function recordMaxSellPrice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("C4:D4");
  var values = range.getValues()[0];
  range.setValues([[values[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to loop?

Comment: no i dont, but i would like to know how

Comment: Try a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 0):

No need for loop.

The following code reads C4:C2000, gets Max Value, sets entire D4:D2000 to Max Value:

```
function recordMaxSellPrice() {
  
  var aSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rng01 =  aSht.getRange("C4:C2000");
  var setRng = rng01.offset(0,1);

  // see Tanaike for flatten and Mat.max.apply
  var anArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], rng01.getValues());
  setRng.setValue(Math.max.apply(null, anArray));

}
```

read [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45203334/1683034) for explanations

also **note** the difference between `setValue` and `setValues`

Comment: Accually i need ever row to be checked for its own max value.
i dont need the Max for all rows together.

`function recordMax() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("C4:D4");
  for (let step = 0; step < 50; step++) { // Runs 50 times, with values of step 0 through 49.
      var nxtRng = range.offset(1, 0);
      var values = range.getValues()[0];
      range.setValues([[values[0], Math.max(values[0], values[1])]]);
  } //loop
}`

i tried this, but that doesnt work.

Comment: 1) Since the question "as you put it" is answered please vote it properly. What you need clearly is different from what you asked, but it is not difficult, just be clear about it.                                           2) There is not much point in finding the max in every row since we only search C column! Please clarify what you really want 1st