# Google Sheets Apps Script : Get max value in a column / in a row / in any range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Some time ago [Dmitry Kostyuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13229211/dmitry-kostyuk) gave me this nice script to get max value in a specific column :

```
var maxValue = sh.getRange(1, 17, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().reduce((max, item) => item[0] > max ? item[0] : max, -Infinity);
```

I'm trying to get the same for a specific row, and for any two-dimensional array, but I can't find what I would need to change then…

Any help would be appreciated…

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

From `I'm trying to get the same for a specific row, and for any two-dimensional array`, I guessed that you might have wanted the following situation.

- You wanted to retrieve the maximum value from the specific row from the Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

If your `sh` is the valid sheet object, how about the following modification? In this case, the maximum value is retrieved from row 5. If you want to change the row, please modify `5` to another row number.

```js
var maxValue = Math.max(...sh.getRange(5, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]);
```

- If this method is used, your showing script `var maxValue = sh.getRange(1, 17, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().reduce((max, item) => item[0] > max ? item[0] : max, -Infinity);` can be also modified as follows.

  ```js
  var maxValue = Math.max(...sh.getRange(1, 17, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat());
  ```

#### References:

- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: Thx a lot Tanaike, meanwhile I also found the "Math.max" here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202902/inputting-an-array-into-math-max-in-google-apps-scripts

I seems the ".flat()" also works for a row…

Comment: I just made some tests.

It appears that for a column, I don't need the ".flat()", the code can just stop with the "getValues()". (It also works with the ".flat()" but not with the "[0]".)

But for a row, I need to have the "[0]" or the ".flat()".

Which seems quite logical.

Comment: @Seb Mainguet Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `It appears that for a column, I don't need the ".flat()", the code can just stop with the "getValues()". (It also works with the ".flat()" but not with the "[0]".) But for a row, I need to have the "[0]" or the ".flat()". Which seems quite logical.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Seb Mainguet Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.